# Limiting down the amount of calls to the database during a simple_form with multiple HABTM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am currently trying to speed up an old (3.2) Rails app and hitting an issue with way too many calls being made to the database during an edit view using `simple_form`

Here is the simplified setup;

```
class Event
  HABTM Speakers
  HABTM Sponsors

class Speaker
  belongs_to Sponsor
  HABTM Events

class Sponsor
  have_many Speakers
  HABTM Events
```

For an event we want to show both each potential speaker (of which there are thousands) and all the sponsors (hundreds).

For each speaker if they have a sponsor they need to show the sponsor name.

This all adds up to **a lot** of calls to the `sponsors` table, way too many.

### Current Code

Right now the simple_form is set up as;

```
<%= simple_form_for [:admin, @event] do |f| %>
...
<%= f.association :speakers, :input_html => { :class => 'select2able' }, :label_method => :summary %>
...
<%= f.association :sponsors, :input_html => { :class => 'select2able' } %>
...
```

That label method is on the `speaker` model;

```
delegate :name, to: :sponsor, prefix: true, allow_nil: true

def summary
  [name, job_title, sponsor_name].compact.join ' - '
end
```

The @event variable is assigned in the controller with a simple

```
@event = Event.find params['id']
```

This is where I have been spending most of my time trying to improve.

### What I have tried

Calling `Event.includes(:speakers => :sponsor).find()` I thought would help. but it hasn't at all.

I have also tried just including speaker and sponsor separately.

I have searched around for people having issues with `simple_form` specifically but haven't found anything. I know this is a sign of the mental structure that was made, but anything I can do to improve it without a complete re-write would be excellent.

Comment: Shouldn't that be: includes(:speakers => :sponsor)

Comment: @DavidAldridge you are right, that was a typo in my question though unfortunately! Editing now

Comment: What do you get with includes(:speakers, :sponsors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was almost there with my original attempts.

This version of Rails didn't like the external includes (it executed but didn't apply anything)

The final code was a slight change where I brought the include inside the find_by.

```
Event.find_by_slug(params[:id], :include => [:speakers, :sponsors, :speakers => :sponsor])
```